# Could not find a part of the path .nuget\packages\.tools\Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools

Tags: asp.net, secret-manager

After having a 4-month break from my .NET project I suddenly run into this error:

```
Could not find a part of the path c:\Users\...myusername...\.nuget\packages\.tools\Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools
```

Can anybody explain why I should suddenly get this kind of error? I have checked that Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools is not found in the path listed here. I will try to install the SecretManager (although I installed it one year ago), but I'm still confused why I get the error now.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your problem?

Comment: No, I don't really remember what resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look if you have the package folder in your local machine, maybe when you added the new packages to a project the TFS marked them as pending to check-in and then later you removed them manually from your hard drive, at that moment the tfs has a package pending to upload that is not physically present on the hard drive and that is the error you are getting